# Simon says without Micro-controller (just using digital logic components)

Tags: digital-logic

I'm doing a *Simon* game as my DLD (Digital Logic Design) project, so I'm asking if it is possible to do it only using DLD components (AND,NOR,NAND,OR,FLIP-FLOPS,....) without doing any programming, just pure hardware.
 I find out a way to generate a random seq. but my important problem is how to Compare between the LEDs and the bush buttons (i mean between what the player entered and the LEDs sequence) Any Help ??!

Comment: Of course it's possible.  It might just take a whole bunch of chips.

Comment: This might be of interest to you.  It's a tear down and explaination of the original simon says game's circuitry.  They used a 4 bit microprocessor.  http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/Reverse_engineering_an_MB_Electronic_Simon_game

Comment: As a hint, I'd imagine shift registers may be prominent in the design

Answer (score 2):

Implementing the game entirely with discrete hardwired logic would probably not be much fun.  Using programmable logic would be less work, but what I would suggest might be most interesting would be to build your own programmable controller so you'd use a few discrete chips and possibly one or two simple programmable logic chips along with a ROM or two (EPROM, flash, or whatever) to hold a program.

One possible design would be to use a couple of 2x64-bit shift register chips, a 74HC165 for input, a 74HC595 for output, a couple of six-bit latch chips, a 64Kx16 ROM chip, and a few NANDs, etc.  Cascade two of the 64-bit stages into a 128-bit stage, and the 595 and 165 into a 16-bit stage.  On each cycle, feed the four outputs from the shifters into the ROM chip along with 12 bits from the latches.  Feed four bits from the ROM to the shifters and one to the load/latch enable of the 165/595.  Feed the other eleven bits, along with the bit feeding the 165/595, to the ROM address latches.  Drive the speaker with the "NAND" of one of the address wires and one of the 595 outputs.

I would expect that the resulting machine could implement a reasonable memory-match game which was about as sophisticated as the Simon® brand one.  The processor would effectively hold 4096 "instructions" of 256 bits each; not great code density by any stretch, but it should be capable of implementing the game.  Adding some additional circuitry could greatly reduce code space requirements [it's not really necessary for all of the bits into and out of the ROM to be independent] but the circuit as described should be interesting to work with.

Comment: Actually constructing it may not be fun, but drawing out a state machine for a very limited example of the game, drawing the Karnough Maps, and working out the logic for a JK flip flop implementation would be a hoot, and quite illuminating

Comment: I think figuring out how to use a ROM-based state machine as described might be more interesting; basically, the described circuitry would give you computational abilities comparable to a small micro, but for the need to wait 64 or 128 cycles for memory to cycle around after each group of operations.  Using an ALU to do math may be faster, but that doesn't mean an ALU is actually necessary.

Comment: I understand your point ,, and i know its more fun doing it with a Microproccesor But its a project for DLD ,,so i only allowed to do it with Digital components such as a counter , Flip_Flops and so on .
I find out a way to generate a random seq. but my important problem is how to Compare between the LEDs and the bush buttons (i mean between what the player entered and the LEDs sequence) Any Help ??!

Comment: @user40782: A ROM chip isn't a microprocessor.  Basically, what you'd be doing would be to build a very simple microprocessor out of some discrete logic, and then using the *homebuilt* microprocessor to run the game.  Very different from using an off-the-shelf processor.  For the random sequence generation, I would suggest using a linear feedback shift register along with a "spare" shift register.  Use something like a 74HC153 multiplexer so that you can have each shift register feed itself unmodified, swap its contents with the other, copy the first register to the second, or...

Comment: "randomize" the first register while the second register holds its contents.  When the system is waiting for the user to push "start", let the first generator randomize things.  Then copy its contents to the second.  When showing the LEDs, run the random generator one step [if it's a 66-bit shifter, clock it 66 times] for each LED flash; the last two shift bits would say which LED should be active.  Then swap the shift register contents and the last two bits of the shifter will identify the first button.  If the correct button is pushed, clock the register 66 times and the bits will give...

Comment: ...the next button.  If you don't use some form of ROM-based state controller, the discrete logic necessary to keep track of how long the light sequence should be, how many lights have been done so far, etc. is apt to be rather overwhelming.  Adding a single ROM chip to the mix could probably get the chip count below a dozen.